# Hide divs if another div has certain text

Tags: javascript, jquery, bigcommerce

Basically, this is a storefront site. I want to be able to have the price display as "Login For Cost" when the customer is not logged in. When not logged in, the price for everything is defaulted to "$0.00".

Along with changing the price to "Login For Cost", I want to hide the divs that contain the "Add to cart" button and compare buttons.

I followed an [example](http://www.protocolthree.com/bigcommerce-tutorial-hide-pricing-until-customer-is-signed-into-a-wholesale-account/) (found under "Adding the Javascript") I found online and this is what I came up with so far..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('.p-price em:contains("$0.00")').text("Login for Cost");
  $('.p-price:contains("$0.00")').text("Login for Cost");
})
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
  if ($('.p-price').html()=='Login for Cost') {
    $('.ProductActionAdd').hide();
    $('.ProductCompareButton').hide();
    $('.CompareButton').hide();
  } else {   
    $('.ProductActionAdd').show();
    $('.ProductCompareButton').show();
    $('.CompareButton').show();
  }
})
</script>
```

The first script works, where the price will be changed to "Login for Cost" when not logged in and displays the actual price when logged in. However, the second script hides the 3 divs both when logged in and not logged in.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you also post the HTML?

Comment: remove else statement ... and try

Comment: Doesn't make much sense. You first set that text....then you try to search for it. Use your server side login status to set a variable at least or a class on body or some way to know if user is logged in or not

Comment: Provide  a [mcve] that includes html structure for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `==` in javascript is a bad practice. Instead use `===` like the following one and see if it works. And also use `.text()` instead of `.html()`:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready( function() {
if ($('.p-price').text()==='Login for Cost') {
//Your code to hide
} else{
//Your code to show
})
</script>
```

Comment: `$(".text_div").text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace("$0.00", "Login for Cost"); 
});​​​​​
`
It was a combination of your help and the above code. Thank you!